# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree while trying to install react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to install react-google-maps and I'm getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: InBetween@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0 " from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-google-maps@9.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-maps
npm ERR!   react-google-maps@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\19088\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\19088\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-08T19_58_56_496Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried forcing it before, but that completely broke the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the package react-google-maps requires an older version of React than what your project is using.

The library you're trying to install, react-google-maps, hasn't been updated in over 5 years. It's requiring you to be using a very old version of React, and you're using a much newer one.

Your options are:

1. Install with --legacy-peer-deps. `npm install react-google-maps --legacy-peer-deps`
2. Downgrade the version of React your project is using.
3. Use a different, newer library.

I would strongly disadvise option #2.

One quick search and I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react

I haven't ever used google maps with React, so there may be a reason you want that specific library, but I noticed that the one I linked has 2-3x as many weekly downloads and was updated months instead of years ago. Just a thought.

Good luck.